# How do I get custom fonts to show up in iOS simulator running iOS 11 or below?

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, ios-simulator, custom-font

When I use Xcode to build and run my app in an iOS simulator (running iOS 11 or below), the custom font text displays as a bunch of question mark boxes. If I run it on an iOS 12 simulator the font displays just fine.

I've been building and testing my app for iOS 12 since I started working on it, with the custom font I added working the whole time, but I've recently tried to test it on an iOS 11 simulator and iOS 10 simulator, but the custom font doesn't work (just shows question marks). I followed all the instructions here (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app) to get the custom font working correctly, but it only works on an iOS 12 simulator.

I'm not sure if it's just a bug with the iOS simulator (as I'm not able to test in on a physical device running iOS 11 or below) or if there was something changed in iOS 12 that I'm relying on to get the custom font working.

UPDATE:
I got this error message in the console: "Requested font not available from file:///Users/[username]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1E6CD4AD-CEBE-4B08-9CDA-1238AC261702/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CBD96873-72AE-434B-B53B-7F1BC8617B83/[app name].app/Cabin-Regular.ttf#postscript-name=Cabin-Regular, fallback to LastResort."

Comment: The fact that the question marks appear suggests to me that the font is "working". If it were not, your attempt to access the font would crash. Hard to say more without knowing what font this is, how you are loading it, what text you are trying to show, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! The font I was using is called Cabin and it's a .ttf file I downloaded from Google Fonts. I tried downloading and importing another font, which also works when I run the iOS 12 simulator but still has the same problem of showing question marks on iOS 11 or iOS 10. It happens when I use any text like "Hello world", for example. I did try creating a new blank Xcode project and importing the font the same way and it actually works in that project, so it must have something to do with the specific Xcode project I'm working on.

Comment: OK, great test! However, we can't tell from here what's different about the specific Xcode project, so it's impossible to help unless you can reproduce the issue.

Comment: You're totally right. I wasn't sure what I could give you to help, but then I just realized I had certain log messages disabled. When I turned them back on I got the error message I just added to the post above. I don't know if that helps much, so if it doesn't then I'll just have to ignore this problem for now and hope it only happens in the simulator.

Comment: Yeah, well, the question marks already told us that (that's the Fallback font). — If you can get this to work fine in a new blank project, there must be some key difference with the one that doesn't work. You forgot to make the font part of the target, or _something_.